# How can I rewrite simple effects fadeIn(), fadeOut(), slideUp(), slideDown() using animate({ })?

Tags: jquery, animation, effects

I cannot understand why it doesn't work now. I write:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('div#box').animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    });
});

div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #000040;
    display: none;
}
```

and it doesn't `fadeIn()`.
How can I do these simple things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: While the below works, looking at the jQuery source reveals that this is much easier:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#box').animate({
            opacity: "show"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the relevant part of the jQuery source, that defines these slideDown/Up/Toggle and fadeIn/Out functions:

```
// Generate shortcuts for custom animations
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx("show", 1),
    slideUp: genFx("hide", 1),
    slideToggle: genFx("toggle", 1),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" }
}, function( name, props ){
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, callback ){
        return this.animate( props, speed, callback );
    };
});
```

---

The CSS rule "`display: none`" doesn't mean it is transparent, it means it is not displayed at all.  You need to set display to `block`, then animate.  You probably want to return `false` in the click function, so that the link doesn't end up taking the user to another page (or you can just set the href attribute to "#", which you may already be doing).

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#box').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#box').css('display', 'block');
        $('#box').animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use preventDefault(); instead of return false;